# How do I change the appearance of the Unity greeter?

Tags: customization, lock-screen, unity-greeter

Is there any way to change the appearance of the Lock Screen on Ubuntu 13.10 (unity)?

At current its simply a black screen with a tiny clock on the upper right corner.

I would like to change this to another image or maybe even change the position and size of the clock if possible.

**Note:** I would like to change the look of the screen when its in the "locked" state as I already have my login screen set how I want, but now I want to adjust the look and feel of the screens while they are locked (pre-password prompt).

Im looking for a "locked" screen more akin to what is seen in Gnome3 and Mint with a large clock and other things displayed. Also, that answer only applies to GDM, not LightDM, which handles the lock screen now.

Comment: It does not need to look like the login screen. Anything else will answer my question. Im looking for a "locked" screen more akin to what is seen in Gnome3 and Mint with a large clock and other things displayed.
Also, that answer only applies to GDM, not LightDM, which handles the lock screen now.